# Close all child tabs when parent tab is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dom-events, window.open

There is a page in asp.net which have a link that opens into a new tab in browser. So when I close my parent tab all the child tabs should be closed.

How can I do that?

My approach was using Javascript but till now not reached too far.

Comment: @ -1 marker can u provide the reason for your curtsy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you call window.open(), you are given a handle:

```
myWindow = window.open(/* open stuff*/);
```

If you keep track of these handles in an array (for example), you can then call:

```
myWindow.close();
```

When you're done.

**Edit**

For example:

```
var wnds = new Array();
```

Whenever you want to open a window:

```
wnds[wnds.length] = window.open(/* open stuff*/);
```

And to close them all

```
for(i = 0; i < wnds.length; ++i)
    wnds[i].close();
```

Comment: this was some thing similar that i was doing but i have two question  1)When user clicks on the small cross button on the browser how can i detect that ? 2) how can i give the index of the window to be closed in the loop.

Comment: You could put the closing code in a function, say `closePopups();`, and then hook in to the `onbeforeunload` event (when the user navigates away), e.g: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { closePopups();}`.  I am not sure if the user hits `X` that this will work (I can't test it at the moment, I'm afraid).

Comment: Thanks MOO i will try it out and regarding my second question can you provide some help